# Angular Prestahsop Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm french, sorry for the bad orthography...

Hello, I am trying to retrieve video links on Prestashop using the WebService Angular.

The form of JSON is:

```
<prestashop> 
<opartproductvideos> 
<opartproductvideo> 
<link> <language id = "1"xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SJV31BsoUc</language>    </link>
</opartproductvideo>
<opartproductvideo>
<link><language id = "1"xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Yyqf388uN4</language></link></opartproductvideo>
<opartproductvideo>
<link><language id = "1"xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gzu9rNgxgsw</language></link></opartproductvideo>
</opartproductvideos>
</prestashop>
```

In the HTML file, I have `<li ng-repeat = "videos in video track by $ id">`.

I get the error

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: videos in video track by videos, Duplicate key: ", Duplicate value: "
```

Would you have any idea?
Cheers,

Comment: As error message suggests just add `track by $index` to your ngRepeat.

Comment: Not to come off as a "smart alleck" but Angular is ***very*** good about describing their errors and how to properly resolve them. Open up your console and click on the link they provide. It gives you instructions on what to do.  Also you are tracking by the id and the id is the same for every element, you need to track by something else... like $index. Side note: Element ids *MUST* be unique.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I think the easiest way would be to replace all strings id = "number" by increasing numbers from 1 (the number of links is undefined), I have unfortunately never made javascript ... This is my debut ... I found the Regex API that could be useful! The expression var regex = / id = "([0-9] +)" /; match correctly
Could you help me?